# Perturbative expansion of the S-matrix in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

Beginner to QFT - While Taylor expanding the exponential term of the S-matrix, why is the 2nd order term (quadratic time integration term) written with two different dummy variables for time? (Lectures on Quantum Field Theory by Ashok Das, page 231)

Comment: Think of an integral as a sum. The second order term is then a product of a sum of terms, which can be expanded into a sum of a product of many terms. This is exactly what is captured by 2 integration variables.

Comment: I would recommend reading chapter 4.2 in Peskin&Schroeder.

Answer (score 1):

Well if they were written with the same dummy variable what would that even mean?

It might help if you think of the integral as a whole as some function of t.

$e^{F(t)}=1+F(t)+\frac{1}{2}F(t)^2+...$

if $F(t)=\int_{t'}^{t} H(t')dt'$, then what would the integral squared be?

Comment: Mathematically, it would just be a square of the integration term. Physically (loosely speaking), it would just be the square of the energy integrated from one point in time to another. P.S.- Moderators, I am commenting in order to reply as I couldn't find the option to reply.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're justifying to yourself that you just square the integrand? In doing so you're completely ignoring the limiting process involved with integration. Take an easy example, not related to QFT specifically. $F(x)=\int _0^x x'dx'$, so F(x) is the area underneath the line y=x, from y=0 to some x. We know that F(1)=0.5 (just the area of a triangle with b=h=1). If we were to then do what you suggest, which is to square the integrand $\int_0^x x'^2dx'=\frac{1}{3}x^3$. If we subbed 1 in to this we'd get $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: But the answer we're looking for is $(F(1))^2=(0.5)^2=0.25$. You need to have the two integrals